# Unable to start JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to install JFrog artifactory into my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system.
I followed this video to install it [JFrog Installation link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFF-jnAxlDs)
In this video his 4th step, he has given the below commands after installing Artifactory.

```
1. nohup sh artifactory.sh &
 after running the command i got the following output 
     ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

2. tail -f nohup.out the output of the given command 

INFO: Deployment of web application directory 
[/home/Downloads/JFrof/artifactory-oss-6.8.3/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [28] ms
Mar 04, 2019 3:49:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Mar 04, 2019 3:49:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
Mar 04, 2019 3:49:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]**
```

am i giving the right commands? can someone help me installing it?

Comment: Did you try following the official installation instructions on the JFrog Documentation?
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-InstallingArtifactory

Comment: Yes i have tried it but still facing the same issue
 ./bin/artifactoryctl check  : activating
 ./bin/artifactoryctl start   :
                       Job for artifactory.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status artifactory.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.when i use those commands i am getting those outputs

Comment: Run `sudo netstat -natp|grep :8081` to find out if a Artifactory instance is already/still running. Check catalina*.log for error messages. Which install method from the official documentation did you use?

Answer (score 0):

find the follwing path and run this

**$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryctl start**

else find bin/artifactoryctl

if you do cd you should see bin (make sure artifactoryctl is present inside bin previously) and run the below command

**bin/artifactoryctl start**